# How do I make a stable connection with SQL Server 2008 and code my first CRUD operations in C++

Tags: c++, .net, sql-server-2008, ado.net, visual-studio-2013

How do I make a connection between my C++ project and SQL Server 2008 ? Refering to some articles on the Internet, the best way is to use ADO.NET API. I've searched some samples of code making the crud operations and showing how to make a DB connection, and [here is the best tutorial that I've found](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2659/ADO-NET-Primer-using-Managed-C).

The issue here, after making a new project New > Visual C++ > Empty Project (.NET Framework 4.5) some errors occured when I've copyied/pasted the first snippet, which is :

```
// This is the main project file for VC++ application project
// generated using an Application Wizard.

#include "stdafx.h"
// Standard
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using <System.dll>
#using <system.data.dll> // This is required for the ADO.NET Provider
#include <tchar.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Data::SqlClient;

// This is the entry point for this application
int _tmain(void)
{
    SqlConnection      * mySQLConnection;
    SqlCommand         * mySQL;
    SqlDataReader      * myReader;

    try
    {
        mySQLConnection = new SqlConnection(
            S"server=local;Trusted_Connection=yes;database=pubs;");
        mySQL = new SqlCommand (S"select * from authors",
            mySQLConnection);

        mySQLConnection->Open (); // Open up the connection
        myReader = mySQL->ExecuteReader ();

        while(myReader->Read ())
            Console::WriteLine(myReader->get_Item("au_lname")->ToString ()); 
    }
    catch(Exception * e)
    {
        Console::Write(e->ToString () );
    }
    __finally
    {
        myReader->Close ();
        mySQLConnection->Close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

here is the first error of 22 :

> 2 IntelliSense: "#using" requires C++/CLI mode c:\Users\Nectarys\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Project2\Project2\Source.cpp

How do I fix this, please ? (If the problem cames from the provider, how do I check if I have it installed and that I have the right version ?)

**Note :** I've included "stdafx.h" into my project. I haven't installed any provider after this copy/paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because your project does not have the Common Language Runtime flag set, so it is trying to compile as native code instead of managed.  To set the flag, right-click on the project and click on Properties, under the general section there is a "Common Language Runtime Support" option.

The tutorial you linked is from 2002 and uses manged C++, which was introduced before CLI/C++.  To compile managed C++, the flag needs to be set to /clr:oldsyntax.  Visual Studio intellisense will give you errors because it does not support managed C++, only CLI/C++.  A migration guide is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235289.aspx, but essentially you need to replace the asterisks in your variable declarations with hats ("^"), use gcnew instead of new, do not put a "S" in front of strings (they're automatically managed strings in managed code), and change how you're accessing an item of the reader to use the array accesssor.  The new code would be this (compile with /clr):

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using <System.dll>
#using <system.data.dll> // This is required for the ADO.NET Provider
#include <tchar.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Data::SqlClient;

// This is the entry point for this application
int _tmain(void)
{
    SqlConnection      ^ mySQLConnection;
    SqlCommand         ^ mySQL;
    SqlDataReader      ^ myReader;

    try
    {
        mySQLConnection = gcnew SqlConnection(
            "server=local;Trusted_Connection=yes;database=pubs;");
        mySQL = gcnew SqlCommand ("select * from authors",
            mySQLConnection);

        mySQLConnection->Open (); // Open up the connection
        myReader = mySQL->ExecuteReader ();

        while(myReader->Read ())
            Console::WriteLine(myReader["au_lname"]->ToString ()); 
    }
    catch(Exception ^ e)
    {
        Console::Write(e->ToString () );
    }
    __finally
    {
        myReader->Close ();
        mySQLConnection->Close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately I do not know of a guide on how to use the SqlClient written in CLI/C++.

Comment: Thanks for response, can you please write a full request based on `gcnew` which the operator is `insert`, please ?

Comment: `gcnew` in CLI/C++ is the same as `new` in managed C++.  There's no difference in usage.  You can use the tutorial and replace `new` with `gcnew` and it will work.